# Airflow RedshiftToS3Operator: using parameters

Tags: airflow, jinja2

I'm tryng to pass parameters into my query sql using `parameters` parameter into a RedshiftToS3Operator. I don't understand how to use my parameters into my query. Here is my query into a `mycode.sql` file:

```
Select * From my_table where 
date_start = {{ data_interval_end.subtract(days=day_as_parameters)}}
```

Using the Operator like this :

```
unload_data_to_s3 = RedshiftToS3Operator(
        task_id="unload_data_to_s3",
        s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        s3_key=S3_KEY,
        select_query="mycode.sql",
        unload_options=["CSV", "ALLOWOVERWRITE", "DELIMITER ','", "PARALLEL OFF", "HEADER"],
        table_as_file_name=False,
        parameters={"day_as_parameters": 10}
    )
```

I tried several format but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have confused the parameters kwarg (for SQL templating) with params kwarg (for Jinja templating). Try using an airflow param instead of an SQL parameter:

```
Select * From my_table where 
date_start = {{ data_interval_end.subtract(days=params.day_as_parameters)}}
```

```
unload_data_to_s3 = RedshiftToS3Operator(
        task_id="unload_data_to_s3",
        s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        s3_key=S3_KEY,
        select_query="mycode.sql",
        unload_options=["CSV", "ALLOWOVERWRITE", "DELIMITER ','", "PARALLEL OFF", "HEADER"],
        table_as_file_name=False,
        params={"day_as_parameters": 10}
    )
```